# Sum half-hourly values to 6-hourly using zApply in Raster package R

Tags: r, date, sum, raster

```
library(raster)
library(zoo)
library(xts)
```

I have a large `rasterBrick` object (`RB`) with `144 layers`.Each layer is separated from the other by 30 minutes time step. The start time for accumulation is `00:00:00–00:30:00 UTC`. Please use `UTC` and not `CST`.

```
date30mins=<-seq(as.POSIXct("2015-04-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2015-04-03 23:59:59"), by="30 mins",tz="GMT") #length (date30mins)=144
```

i.e. `date30mins`

```
 "2015-04-01 00:00:00 UTC"
 "2015-04-01 00:30:00 UTC" 
 "2015-04-01 01:00:00 UTC"
 "2015-04-01 01:30:00 UTC"
 "2015-04-01 02:00:00 UTC" 
 "2015-04-01 02:30:00 UTC" 
 "2015-04-01 03:00:00 UTC" 
 "2015-04-01 03:30:00 UTC"
 "2015-04-01 04:00:00 UTC" 
 "2015-04-01 04:30:00 UTC" 
 "2015-04-01 05:00:00 UTC" 
 "2015-04-01 05:30:00 UTC" and so on...
```

becomes: `dates6hourly`

`(i.e. sum values from 00:00:00 UTC to 05:30:00 UTC;06:00:00 UTC to 11:30:00 UTC)`

```
`dates6hourly`=seq(as.POSIXct("2015-04-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2015-04-03 23:59:59"), by="6 hours",tz="GMT")

"2015-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" 
"2015-01-01 06:00:00 UTC" and so on
```

How can one implement this using `zApply`?

My data set is too large to make a reproducible example via `dput` but sample data can be found here [sample data set](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ppmpq2h7ikqc0mo/sampleData.RData?dl=0)

**EDIT**

The following should accomplish the task but I get an error:

```
index=rep(seq(1,12,by=1),each=12)
ras <- setZ(RB,date30mins)
6hrly <- zApply(ras,by=index, FUN=sum);

Error: unexpected symbol in "6hrly"
```

Probably `zApply` does not recognize `"index"`?

Within `package::rts` this can easily be done using:

```
rasrts=rts(x=RB,time=dates30mins)
agg <- period.apply(rasrts,index,sum)#rts
```

But I would like to implement using the `raster` package.

Comment: A reproducible example need not have all your data: just a minimal subset, say, 18 layers of a spatial subset of your massive rasterBrick.

Comment: @Shekeine thanks I have provided a subset of the rasterbrick. See above.

Answer (score 0):

I got it using `raster package` `stackApply`  function.

library(raster)
    library(zoo)
    library(xts)

```
index=rep(seq(1,12,by=1),each=12)
ras <- setZ(RB,date30mins)
sixhrly <- stackApply(ras,indices=index, fun=sum);
```